# Linechart needs a "baseline"

Tags: mpandroidchart

I have a line chart which goes from 1 to -1. I want a white solid line to appear through the chart at 0 as a "baseline". I've tried adding a "limit" line but nothing displays onscreen. Please see my code below.

```
            // Limit Line
            LimitLine baseline = new LimitLine(0f,"baseline");
            baseline.setLineWidth(4f);
            baseline.setLineColor(Color.rgb(255,210,60));
            baseline.enableDashedLine(8f, 5f, 0f);
            baseline.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
            baseline.setTextSize(12f);
           // baseline.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);


            //set yAxis
            YAxis yLeftAxis = mLineChart.getAxisLeft();
            YAxis yRightAxis = mLineChart.getAxisRight();
            yLeftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
            yRightAxis.setEnabled(false);
            yLeftAxis.setEnabled(false);
            yLeftAxis.setAxisMaximum(1.5f);
            yLeftAxis.setAxisMinimum(-1.5f);
            yLeftAxis.addLimitLine(baseline);

            // draw limit lines behind data instead of on top
            yLeftAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasnt showing because I had the yAxis disabled

yRightAxis.setEnabled(false);
 yLeftAxis.setEnabled(false);

Changing yLeftAxis to (true) displays the limit line now.